# how to get the values from meta tag in adobe launch or adobe analytics

Tags: javascript, meta-tags, adobe-analytics, tealium, adobe-launch

In meta tag, The "name" attribute as the variable name and the "content" attribute as the value of that variable.

```
<meta name="pageType" content="category" />
 <meta name="Country" content='india'/>
```

The variable will capture as: pageType = "category" 
when "pageType" match with condition then the value of "category" should go to into "evars"
example :-
evar5 = category and 
evar6 = india.

Comment: Why did you tag your question with "tealium"? Are you looking for a solution in both Launch _and_ Tealium?

Answer (score 0):

You can try and do something like this to get the name and content of the meta tags and trigger your Adobe tag. You can add any "if" conditions on the name and content to only pass certain values. Additionally, you will need to map "name" and "content" to the corresponding eVars on the Adobe tag.

```
var temp_obj = {};
var metaElements = document.getElementsByTagName('meta');
for (var i = 0; i < metaElements.length; i++) {
    temp_obj.name = metaElements[i].name;
    temp_obj.content = metaElements[i].content;
    utag.link(temp_obj, null, [{UID of your Adobe Tag}])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got it.

var meta = document.getElementsByTagName("meta");
    size = meta.length;

```
for(var i=0; i<size; i++) {
    if(meta[i].getAttribute("name")== "pwc_publication_date")
    {
        s.eVar6 = meta[i].getAttribute("content");
    }
    if(meta[i].getAttribute("name")== "pwc_title")
    {
        s.eVar5= meta[i].getAttribute("content");
    }
    if(meta[i].getAttribute("name")== "pwc_articletype")
    {
        s.eVar7= meta[i].getAttribute("content");       }
    if(meta[i].getAttribute("name")== "pwc_modified_date")
    {
        s.eVar8= meta[i].getAttribute("content");       }
    if(meta[i].getAttribute("name")== "pwc_tags")
    {
        s.eVar9= meta[i].getAttribute("content");       }   
    if(meta[i].getAttribute("name")== "pwc_headline_image")
    {
        s.eVar10= meta[i].getAttribute("content");      }   
}
```

if you change the meta tags order also, you can store values into a particular variables.

Thanks for Help....